# How to dyanmic create a new entity (table) via CoreData model?

Tags: ios, core-data

I want to create a new Entity (table) in SQLite. My code is as follows:

```
+(BOOL)CreateDataSet:(NSManagedObjectModel *) model  
    attributes:(NSDictionary*)attributes 
    entityName:(NSString*) entityName 
{ 
    NSEntityDescription *entityDef = [[NSEntityDescription alloc] init];

    [entityDef setName:entityName];
    [entityDef setManagedObjectClassName:entityName];
    [model setEntities:[NSArray arrayWithObject:entityDef]];
    NSArray *properties =   [CoreDataHelper CreateAttributes:attributes];
    [entityDef setProperties:properties];

    [entityDef release];

    return TRUE;
}
```

But it throws errors:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'Can't modify an immutable model.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01c5abe9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01daf5c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreData                            0x0152634a -[NSManagedObjectModel(_NSInternalMethods) _throwIfNotEditable] + 106
    3   CoreData                            0x01526904 -[NSManagedObjectModel setEntities:] + 36
....
```

That seems to show the model is read only.

Comment: A warning: Core Data is not SQL. Entities are not tables. Objects are not rows. Columns are not attributes. Core Data is an object graph management system that may or may not persist the object graph and may or may not use SQL far behind the scenes to do so. Trying to think of Core Data in SQL terms will cause you to completely misunderstand Core Data and result in much grief and wasted time.

Answer (score 6):

[From the documentation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectModel_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (emphasis is mine)

> Managed object models are editable
>   until they are used by an object graph
>   manager (a managed object context or a
>   persistent store coordinator). This
>   allows you to create or modify them
>   dynamically. However, once a model is
>   being used, it must not be changed.
>   This is enforced at runtime—when the
>   object manager first fetches data
>   using a model, the whole of that model
>   becomes uneditable. Any attempt to
>   mutate a model or any of its
>   sub-objects after that point causes an
>   exception to be thrown. **If you need to
>   modify a model that is in use, create
>   a copy, modify the copy,** and then
>   discard the objects with the old
>   model.

Comment: but how to ? I try to new Model and use NSPersistentStoreCoordinator method 'addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error' save the model as new sqlite file , but failed ......

Answer (score 2):

I quote Apple's Documentation which describes it very accurately:

> Entity descriptions are editable until
>   they are used by an object graph
>   manager. This allows you to create or
>   modify them dynamically. However, once
>   a description is used (when the
>   managed object model to which it
>   belongs is associated with a
>   persistent store coordinator), it must
>   not (indeed cannot) be changed. This
>   is enforced at runtime: **any attempt to
>   mutate a model or any of its
>   sub-objects after the model is
>   associated with a persistent store
>   coordinator** causes an exception to be
>   thrown. If you need to modify a model
>   that is in use, create a copy, modify
>   the copy, and then discard the objects
>   with the old model.

Comment: how do we replace old model with newly created model?

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation for [`NSManagedObjectModel`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectModel_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> **Editing Models Programmatically**
>
> Managed object models are editable
>   until they are used by an object graph
>   manager (a managed object context or a
>   persistent store coordinator). This
>   allows you to create or modify them
>   dynamically. However, once a model is
>   being used, it must not be changed.
>   This is enforced at runtime—when the
>   object manager first fetches data
>   using a model, the whole of that model
>   becomes uneditable. Any attempt to
>   mutate a model or any of its
>   sub-objects after that point causes an
>   exception to be thrown. If you need to
>   modify a model that is in use, create
>   a copy, modify the copy, and then
>   discard the objects with the old
>   model.

In other words, edit your managed object model before you set up your persistent store coordinator or managed object context.

Comment: Hi, would possible show some code for this purpose ? thanks a lots

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore CoreData if you want to create entities dynamically, try SQLite (please use the magical FMDB library), it won't let you down.

Please note that SQLite/FMDB does not support iCloud.